# How to set up Firebase with PhoneGap?

Tags: firebase, cordova, phonegap

I'm trying to build an application with three text fields for a name, email, and contact. When the form is submitted, the data should be saved to Firebase.

I've followed the following steps to set up the environment:

1. I created an account on Firebase.
2. I set up a new project over there.
3. I provided the package name of my personal project (which is created by using command prompt by entering the command 'phonegap create TestProject com.testproject.app')
4. Then, I selected 'Add Firebase to your Android App' on the website, and downloaded the `google-services.json` file.
5. I have pasted that file in the root folder of my project.
6. Now, according to [the `cordova-plugin-firebase` docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase), I should enter a command in the command prompt to add the Firebase plugin to my project, but it returns an error.

As an alternative, I've also tried to add the plugin to the `config.xml` file manually (as mentioned on the website above). But still, it's not working.

I have also followed [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DvRGNrGpI_A). but I'm still stuck at the same stage.

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: What is the exact error returned? Also, the google-services.json file might be required in the platforms/android folder, not just the root folder of your app.

Comment: I am facing **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND** in browser. 

And while running the app using cmd, i am facing the given issue: 
**Exceution failed for tast ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.firstfirebaseproject.app'**

Comment: Also, /platform/android folder already contains the google-service.json file

Comment: The youtube link is for push notification not for the firebase cloud storage.